# Are mounting the rails engine in routes.rb and include it in gemfile (or gemspec) file the same?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines

We are using rails engine in our 3.2.8 app. When we want to include an `engine` in our rails app/another engine, we did include the `engine` in `gemfile(gemspec)` and mounting it in `routes.rb.` However we notice that if we remove the mounting command in `routes.rb` and only leave `gem engine` in `gemfile (gemspec)` file unchanged, the same rpsec cases can pass without error. This leads us wondering what's the difference between mounting rails engine in `routes.rb` and put it in `gemfile` (gemspec for engine) or do both.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure your tests are comprehensive? By adding `mount Smthng => '/path'` to your routes.rb you're specifying the way/path/entrance of using some engine. How did your tests pass after removing the mention of engine in your routes if you had removed this 'link'? Perhaps you've made only some low-level module tests w/o taking into consideration high-level integration tests that span both your app and your engine(s).

Comment: As the post indicates, only some rspec tests. No integration test. We want to understand the difference.

Comment: According to rails engine guide, mounting a engine requires both mounting in parent's routes.rb and put it in gemfile/gemspec.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to mount a Rails Engine in a Rails application, you add the gem to the application's Gemfile (so that the gem's source code will be required when the application boots). You specify the mount path in the application's `config/routes.rb` so that the Engine's controllers will respond to HTTP requests:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  mount MyGem::Engine => "/mygem"

  root to: 'home#index'

end
```

When you are creating an engine, by default, the generator will create a "dummy" application that your tests will use to test your engine. My guess is that your tests are still passing because you still have this mount path specified in the dummy app.